# jQuery onBlur only works on second click out

Tags: jquery, load

For some reason my code below only works when I click out of my input a second time is there a way to make it load the first time?

```
function postTitleCheck() {
    $('.postForm').on('blur', '#post_title', function (e) {
        alert('hi');
        $(".postForm #post_url_link").blur();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.postForm').on('blur', '#post_title', function (e) {
        alert('hi');
        $(".postForm #post_url_link").blur();
    });

    function postTitleCheck() {
        $(".postForm #post_title").blur();
    }
});
```

> Don't Register the event handler in the function.As function is called
>   a new event handler is registered every time which leads to many event
>   handler.

example

```
click 1 - handler count -1
click 2 - handler count -2
click 3 - handler count -3
..... and so on
```

and wrap you code in [DOM ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Works but I get Uncaught ReferenceError: postTitleCheck is not defined